# Which level of Super Saiyan was Vegeta in Episode 8 of Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Vegeta was able to hit Beerus a few times in his episode 8 Super Saiyan level while Goku at Super Saiyan 3 was not able to. Canonically, Vegeta has never gone Super Saiyan 2 before (unless you consider Majin Vegeta to be Super Saiyan 2).

So which level did he go to in this episode? Super Saiyan 2 or something ascended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He was at Super Saiyan 2, as you can clearly see the lightning/sparks around him. His hair didn't change its size. So SS3 is excluded.

This is probably the reason why Goku said Vegeta had surpassed him (in the Battle of Gods movie) at that specific time. Because at SS2, Vegeta was stronger than SS3 Goku.

And yes, Majin Vegeta was Super Saiyan 2 as well :)

Comment: He was also stronger than SS3 Gotenks. So I guess SS3 > SS2 is not always true.

Comment: Oh it's been a long time since I watched the Battle of Gods movie. Didn't know/remember Goku acknowledged that Vegeta surpassed him. Thanks.